# Validation not working on popup

Tags: jquery, validation, bootstrap-modal

While using `bootstrapValidator(`) if am firing it on a form which appears on popup, the validation never works or even triggers.

I understand that I was using the method on `document.ready()` in jQuery and hence tried switching to `.focusout` and `.blur` but they are not working too. Any ideas?

jQuery -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#brochure-form').bootstrapValidator({
    //THE CODE   
    })
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
    //THE CODE
    });
});
```

HTML -

```
<form action="........" method="post" class="wpcf7-form well form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate" id="brochure-form">
    <div style="display: none;">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="408">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="4.4.2">
        <input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="en_US">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap text-680"><input type="text" name="text-680" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name"></span>
                </div>
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12 inputGroupContainer">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span><span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap email-80"><input type="email" name="email-80" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Email"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form nested within another form the validator will not work. 
You can have multiple forms on one page but they should not be nested.

If this is the case remove the nested form.

Comment: am not using nested form